# RABL vs Json Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance, comparison, rabl, jsonbuilder

As part of a team, we are building an RoR application completely driven through API's. We already have a web app, its just that we now want to make it completely API driven. We initially kicked off with using [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) Templating Engine for generating the JSON Response. We recently observed that by using [JSON Builder](https://github.com/dewski/json_builder) as an alternative to RABL, our response times increased by about half a second for an API call in our app that users would hit most often . Before we take a final call on deciding to use JSON Builder for all our API's going forward, I just wanted to know about the pros and cons of using RABL and JSON. Also, it would be nice if one could **compare** the two templating engines **mainly keeping performance in mind** wherever feasible.

Sharing any relevant links would also be helpful.

Kindly let me know your experiences with the usage of both these templating engines. Thank you.

Comment: Marking as "not constructive", as this is a polling type of question. Both have their pros and cons. You will need to choose which one you want. There are ways to improve the responses for Rabl. For instance, you could cache the responses.

Comment: @RyanBigg I need the pros and cons of both so that it can help me decide on which to use based on my applications requirement. I am not planning to decide on what templating engine to use just on the basis of a vote count. I need additional details to take this call for the app. Would appreciate your understanding on this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: @RyanBigg Okay, so in that case if I modify this question asking for code e.g.'s to help differentiate between the two templating engines, would that sound more appropriate ? If not, can you please suggest me how can I edit this question appropriately keeping my requirement in mind ?

Comment: I found some pointers:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571477/rabl-jbuilder-or-manual-json-build-for-api , https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/45 .